# retaining value of a variable after application is closed and reopened

Tags: vb.net, winforms

how do you save the value of a variable for later if the application is closed and reopened in winforms, vb.net?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes.  Just save it in the [Application Settings](http://visualbasic.about.com/od/usingvbnet/a/appsettings.htm).

Comment: this is a great tutorial. however it is not working for me. Form1.BackColor = ColorDialog1.Color
            My.Settings.last_color = Form1.BackColor

Comment: You need to add the setting explicitly, either on the form or project.  See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/25zf0ze8.aspx

Comment: do i have to call something onload?

Answer (score 1):

yes by using cookies.

```
Response.Cookies("userName").Value = "yourvalue"
Response.Cookies("userName").Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(2)
```

But the cookie must be created on that machine

Comment: in a windows application not in the browser

Comment: i don't think it matters...as long as the cookie is created on the machine the windows form will try to access it on.